# Store methods to variables and use them in a ternary in C#

Tags: c#

I have a simple bit of code that I am struggling to make it simpler for my ternary.

I got a method which is quite long and want to shove it into a variable so its easier to read but am not sure how to do it.

My code looks like this currently:

```
_gridPositionLastFrame = _buildState == BuildState.None ? Grids.Snap(worldPosition,1,plane); : Grids.Snap(worldPosition,4,plane);
```

I would like to shorten it something more like:

```
//Set the functions in variables here first some how rather than compute them
//var snapOne as Grids.Snap(worldPosition,1,plane);
//var snapFour as Grids.Snap(worldPosition,4,plane);
_gridPositionLastFrame = _buildState == BuildState.None ? SnapOne() : SnapFour();
```

Is this possible ? It would really help make my script a heck of a lot cleaner in some parts but i do not know the correct way to write it.

Comment: Is that a typo that you're putting `;`'s inside of your conditional operators?

Comment: Yes sorry :) edited it out. I've not slept for 30 hours so im running on fumes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close:

```
var snapOne as Grids.Snap(worldPosition, 1, plane);
var snapFour as Grids.Snap(worldPosition, 4, plane);
_gridPositionLastFrame = _buildState == BuildState.None ? snapOne : snapFour;
```

...but `Grids.Snap` is being called twice, even if one of those calls isn't used. That might even cause side-effects in the case of some methods. I'd recommend extracting out the part that varies instead:

```
var snapSize = _buildState == BuildState.None ? 1 : 4;
_gridPositionLastFrame = Grids.Snap(worldPosition, snapSize, plane);
```

This requires less repeating of logic.

Comment: Oh damn that second option is so much better than what i was trying to do ! Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the signature of your `GridSnap` function, but I'm going to assume it looks like:

```
TR GridSnap(T1, int, T2)
```

So, you could write code that looks like:

```
Func<TR> SnapOne = () => Grids.Snap(worldPosition, 1, plane);
Func<TR> SnapFour = () => Grids.Snap(worldPosition, 4, plane);
```

just above your ternary.

Comment: Take @Jacob's answer instead

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this (For ref and out type methods, this won’t work)

```
_gridPositionLastFrame = Grids.Snap(worldPosition,  _buildState == BuildState.None ? 1: 4 ,plane);
```